# Steam will not launch on HP Chromebook

Tags: games, steam, chromebook

I recently started running Ubuntu on my HP Chromebook (unsure which model), using Crouton. I tried installing steam, but the steam launcher says it's missing the following 32 bit Libraries.
libc.so.6
I had already tried
    [sudo apt-get install libc.so.6]
But that didn't work. I tried deletiing steam, then reinstalling via the terminal. Didn't work.
I downloaded with the site.

Comment: You need to be sure about the hardware you own as many troubleshooting you may need depends on the hardware. The error so far suggests you have an ARM based chromebook, not a x86_64. If so, forget it and move on, your hardware is not compatible.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I believe none of the HP Chromebooks are ARM. However, OP needs to install the 32-bit version of wine/steam.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Thanks for the correction. I'll have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You need the 32-bit version of Wine or Steam. You have an x86 (i386) processor, which means that you cannot use the 64-bit versions of Steam and/or Wine.

Wine is by default 32-bit, but you need to install the correct version of Steam.

Run this command to fix libc.so.6 dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install '^libc6.*'
```

I also recommend avoiding Steam's website installation. Install from Ubuntu repositories via:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```